Tree traversal function works correctly inside loop but not outside
I am trying to solve exercise 6.3 from the K&R C programming book. The text is:

Write a cross-referencer that prints a list of all words in a document, and for each word, a list of the line numbers on which it occurs. Remove noise words like "the,"
"and," and so on.

Here is my solution (i have not removed any noise word but is not important for now):
struct lnode {
    int linen;
    lnode *next;
};

struct tnode {
    char *value;
    tnode *left;
    tnode *right;
    lnode *lines;
};

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXWORD 8192

int getword (char *word, int size, int *line);
void displaytree (struct tnode *node);
struct tnode* addtree (struct tnode *node, char *word, int line);
void deletetree (struct tnode *node);
void displaylines (struct lnode *node);

char noisewords [][MAXWORD] = {"the", "and"};


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct tnode *root;
    // initialize FIRST root to null
    root = NULL;

    int line = 0;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    while (getword(word, MAXWORD, &line) != EOF) {
        root = addtree(root, word, line);
    }

    displaytree(root);
    deletetree(root);
}


void displaytree (struct tnode *node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        displaytree (node -> left);
        printf("(%s)", node -> value);
        displaylines (node -> lines);
        displaytree (node -> right);
    }
    
}

void displaylines (struct lnode *node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d", node -> linen);
        displaylines(node -> next);
    } 
}

/* for malloc and free */
#include <stdlib.h>

void deletelist(struct lnode *listnode) {
  if(listnode != NULL) {
    deletelist(listnode->next);
    free(listnode);
  }
}

void deletetree (struct tnode *node) {

    struct tnode *temp = NULL;

    if (node != NULL) {
        if (node -> right != NULL) {
            temp = node;
            deletetree(temp -> right);
        }
        if (node -> left != NULL) {
            temp = node;
            deletetree(temp -> left);
      }
      if (node -> value != NULL) {
        free(node -> value);
      }
      
      if (node -> lines != NULL) {
        deletelist(node -> lines);
      }

      free(node);
      node = NULL;
    }
}

struct tnode* talloc (void);
char* strdup (char *word);
struct lnode* addline (int line);

struct tnode* addtree (struct tnode *node, char *word, int line) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = talloc();
        if (node != NULL) {
            node -> value = strdup(word);
            node -> left = NULL;
            node -> right = NULL;
            node -> lines = addline(line);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (strcmp(word, node -> value) == 0) {
            /* should not happen, if node != NULL then also node -> lines is different from NULL. */
            if (node -> lines == NULL) {
                node -> lines = addline(line);
            }
            else {
                struct lnode *current = node -> lines;
                while (current -> next != NULL) {
                    current = current -> next;
                }
                current -> next = addline(line);
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, node -> value) < 0) {
            node -> left = addtree (node -> left, word, line);
        }
        else {
            node -> right = addtree (node -> right, word, line);
        }
    }    
    return node;
}

struct lnode* lalloc (void);

struct lnode* addline (int line) {
    struct lnode *node = lalloc();
    if (node != NULL) {
        node -> linen = line;
        node -> next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

struct tnode* talloc (void) {
    return (struct tnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

struct lnode* lalloc (void) {
    return (struct lnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
}

char* strdup (char *word) {
    char *p;
    p = (char *)malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p, word);
    return p;
}

int getch (void);
void ungetch (int c);

int getword (char *word, int size, int *line) {
    int c, getch(void);
    void ungetch(int);
    char *w = word;

    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;

    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    
    if (!isalpha(c)) {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }

    for ( ; --size > 0; w++)
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
            /* count the number line */
            if (*w == '\n')
                *line += 1;
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}

#define BUFSIZE 1000
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufc = 0;

int getch (void) {
    return (bufc > 0) ? buf[--bufc] : getchar();
}

void ungetch (int c) {
    if (bufc >= BUFSIZE) {
        printf("The buffer is full!\n");
        return;
    }
    buf[bufc++] = c; 
}

However, if I give as input something like:
the pen is on the table

the cat is under the table

The output provided is:
(cat)(is)(on)(pen)

By executing the displaytree inside the while loop:
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct tnode *root;
    // initialize FIRST root to null
    root = NULL;

    int line = 0;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    while (getword(word, MAXWORD, &line) != EOF) {
        root = addtree(root, word, line);
        printf("[");
        displaytree(root);
        printf("]\n");
    }
    deletetree(root);
}


I obtain as output:
[(the)]
[(pen)(the)]
[(is)(pen)(the)]
[(is)(on)(pen)(the)]
[(is)(on)(pen)(the)]
[(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)]
[(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)]
[(cat)(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)]
[(cat)(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)]
[(cat)(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)(under)]
[(cat)(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)(under)]
[(cat)(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)(under)]

Which, not considering the previous input, gives as last line: [(cat)(is)(on)(pen)(table)(the)(under)] in which all the nodes of the tree are given.
Why isn't the tree correctly displayed/built outside the while?

Are you compiling this with a C++ compiler? You're using tnode and lnode without the struct keyword before them, which isn't allowed in C unless you add a typedef.

When I run your program with that input (after fixing the above problem), the output I get is (cat)1(is)01(on)0(pen)0(table)12(the)0011(under)1

Ignoring the line numbers that come from displaylines, it's the same as the last line of the output from your version that prints inside the loop.

I am compiling with g++. Which error do you mean? Not using the struct keyword before tnode and lnode?

If you're compiling with g++ then you're creating a C++ program, not a C program.  If this is your intention, then change the question's tag from [tag:c] to [tag:c++] but be prepared for a lot of comments on better ways to write it using modern C++ features.  If you meant to write a C program, then compile it with gcc and fix the errors you will receive, then edit your question with the updated code if the problem persists.

That said, except for the need to say struct tnode and struct lnode everywhere, I don't think there's anything that should behave differently in C++ vs. C. Certainly the symptom they report is not dependent on which language they use.

But since the erroneous output doesn't have the line counts, I'm pretty sure you weren't running the program you posted.

@Barmar the output i provided didn't include the displaylines() function. That said, by solving the issues you pointed out, now the program behaves as expected. Thank you. @Nate Eldredge, now i am compiling with gcc. The code didn't have issues except for the absence of the struct keyword.
